# How to get php echo and die messages to work with jQuery notice plugin

Tags: php, notifications, echo, die

I've created a contact form and it's set up to send the form contents via a mail.php file. At the moment it brings up a success/error message on a new blank page via echo and die respectively, but I want to have some kind of notification that pops up on the current page instead.

The solution I'd like to use is http://www.sandbox.timbenniks.com/projects/jquery-notice/, but the demo on that site uses an example of adding the notification to a button. What I need to do is add the notification in place of the echo or die output message. Is this possible?

Here's the mail.php code I'm using...

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  if (isset($_POST['service'])) {
    $service = $_POST['service'];
    // $service is an array of selected values
  }
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $formcontent=" Message received from wwww.jhnormanandsons.co.uk: \n \n From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n \n Service required: $service \n \n Message: $message";
  $recipient = "jasonbradberry@gmail.com";
  $subject = "You have a new message from $name";
  $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
  mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
  echo ("Thank you for your message. We'll be in touch as soon as we can.");
?>
```

Here's the form HTML...

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="mail.php" name="jh_contact">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required />
  <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" required ></textarea>
  <select name="service">
    <option>Service required</option>
    <option value="MOT">MOT</option>
    <option value="Service / repairs">Service / repairs</option>
    <option value="Cars for sale">Cars for sale</option>
    <option value="Welding">Welding</option>
    <option value="Exhausts">Exhausts</option>
    <option value="Tyres">Tyres</option>
    <option value="Brakes">Brakes</option>
    <option value="Diagnostics">Diagnostics</option>
    <option value="Vehicle checks">Vehicle checks</option>
    <option value="Courtesy car">Courtesy car</option>
    <option value="Advice">Advice</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit-button" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd have the form work with JavaScript disabled too, and then use jQuery to POST the form to the page and parse any normal success messages that way.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    // process form
    if ($sent === true) {
        $alert_class = 'success';
        $alert_test = 'Your enquiry was sent successfully.';
    }
    else {
        $alert_class = 'error';
        $alert_text = 'There was an error sending your enquiry.';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
<?php if (isset($alert_text)): ?>
    <div class="alert <?php echo $alert_class; ?>">
      <p><?php echo $alert_text; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <form action="" method="post" id="contact-form">
      <!-- your form -->
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then the jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    $('#contact-form').submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            var alert_text = $(response).find('.alert').text();
            alert(alert_text);
        });
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery post to submit your form. and get the notification message to display as json...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

search for this line to submit your form using jquery

"Example: send form data using ajax requests"...

on response.. write this code(taken from the notification link u added)

jQuery.noticeAdd({
            text: data , //ur notification msg
            stay: true
    });